# How to implement swipable pages in Android Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-keypad

I've got around to implementing modes on Android keyboard (using the  android:keyboardMode attribute for rows), but I have no idea how to implement pages as [many other keyboards do for emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88xSd.jpg).

Is there some resource I'm overlooking to implement the these in Android?

What I want are many pages (or scrollview) in an Android Keyboard. But all I can come up with is using switching Modes, or using swipeLeft or swipeRight on KeyboardView, which doesn't do the job as the Listener is called only after the swiping has been performed.

Comment: Probably explaining **what** issue you're having is more helpful to understand what your problem is.

Comment: I edited the question to try to clarify it better.
My issue is that I've no idea how to implement pages in the keyboard. I've seen them in other apps, but can't find any resource in the docs which'd help me do that.